# How to have line-breaks in a table cell only after a maximum width in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with cells that could have long content. I want to display the content without line breaks if it does not exceed a certain width.

If the table exceeds the width of the parent element, the default behaviour is to break everything as soon as possible inside the table-cell. The cell takes the width of the longest word in the column.

If I use `white-space: nowrap;` it does not break at all. If I apply `max-width: 60px;` the cell does not extend up to that width. `table-layout: fixed;` does also not work, as the width of the table should expand if needed. `min-width: 60px;` is also not what I want, because I want the columns as short as possible if the text is not long.

This is the default behaviour:

```
This | LongerWord | Normal |
is a |            |        |
long |            |        |
text |            |        |
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```
This is a | LongerWord | Normal |
long cell |            |        |
```

In the following example I would like to display all cells but the very long one in just one line. The long one should break after a certain length, for example after 350px, which would be after `should`. The second row should all be in one line:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  /*max-width: 350px;*/
  /*min-width: 350px;*/
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>short</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can find a solution with JavaScript, but is this possible to do in pure CSS?

```js
for (const td of document.querySelectorAll('td')) {
  if (td.clientWidth > 350) {
    td.style.minWidth = '350px';
    td.style.whiteSpace = 'normal';
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>short</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: It seems it is not really possible to tell the table layout rendering in the browser to shorten cells only in specific cases. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: Can you use JS?

Comment: Add more rows on your example to clarify your question.

Comment: @RahulVerma I want to solve this in CSS if it is possible

Comment: @abrsh I added another row, the problem arrises with one row already, though

Comment: I asked so bcoz I think it isn't possible to get width of longest word in CSS, you'll have to go for JS. However, if you have only one word as longest in a column, then it is possible in CSS. So do you have "LongestWord" as a single word?

Comment: I do not want to break after the longest word but only if a certain width is exceeded. For example after `this is a`. Breaking after the longest word is the default behaviour as you can see in the example.

Comment: I don't think you got my question. I was asking that is "LongerWord" the only word in the column always. Or do you have other words with it?

Comment: No, it could be any text.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you have under "this is a long cell" a "normal" text? It would be impossible for the "normal" cell to auto shrink to wrap the text in your case, because you're using the `<table>` tag. Or do you have a predefined structure for your table? Will your first column always wrap a long text?

Comment: @SebastianI. I would want to have that column to have the max-width which is 60px in my example. I will update my html example to clarify this a little bit.

Comment: Ok, I understand your requirements, but you can't use `max-width` or `max-height` attributes on table cells. What you can do is to set a fixed width for your table cell and wrap the `<td>` content inside a `<div>` and set the div's `max-width` to a custom size. [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#min-max-widths) you can see that the `max-width` for table cells is undefined in CSS.

Comment: @SebastianI. That it is undefined does somehow make sense, as the browsers table layout engine seems to try to make table cells as small if possible if the table exceeds the parents elements width. This does get in each others way.

Comment: answered and then saw you had already worked out a clean JS way to do this since I started answering. Will leave my answer in as it answers the main question you have, no it is not possible. Hopefully one suggestion will help you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

What you want is not possible. You cannot keep the current HTML, add a max width to a table cell, keep table cells at their minimum widths and have words break without using JavaScript.

There are however some good alternatives that apply to most of your requirements.

### Option 1 - overflow within a cell.

By applying `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow-y` you can use `max-width`. The down side is that you have to scroll in the cell.

```css
td {
   white-space:nowrap;
   border: 1px solid black;
   max-width: 350px;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>short</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Option 2 - Minor markup change

If you can apply a class to the ones you know are too long then this becomes trivial. Obviously this assumes you have static data (at which point you would probably just set each column width precisely anyway).

```css
td {
   white-space:nowrap;
   border: 1px solid black;
   max-width: 350px;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}
.long{
   white-space: normal;
   min-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td class="long">Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>short</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Option 3 - some super light weight JavaScript magic

If you combine our previous example (adding a class to a table cell) with a quick check if a table cell is too large we get a solution that is light-weight and will work with dynamic data / without having to worry about breaking things if you change data.

```js
var maxWidth = 350;
var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for(x = 0; x < tableCells.length; x++){
   if(tableCells[x].clientWidth > 350){ //please note if you want this to include the border width then you need to use tableCells[x]..offsetWidth to include the border.
      tableCells[x].classList.add("long");
   }
}
```

```css
td {
   white-space:nowrap;
   border: 1px solid black;
   max-width: 350px;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}
.long{
   white-space: normal;
   min-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>short</td>
<td>short</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>This is a long text</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>LongerWord</td>
<td>Normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Option 4 - change your HTML

If you can change your HTML (i.e. this isn't tabular data) then grouping items by column in divs makes this easy to solve. I am not going to do an example for this as I have a feeling this would not be an option.

### Option 5 - do the work server side

You could count the characters on the server and set the CSS class server side if you REALLY want to avoid JavaScript (so add `class="long"` on the server based on character count).

Although this won't be exact it should be as close and allow you to have dynamic data **without any JavaScript**.

### Conclusion

Someone needs to invent a CSS property to fix this as it is a real pain!

I would go for option number 3, it is clean, easy to implement into an existing solution and easy to maintain. It also beats trying to add inline styles via JavaScript as it will still comply with a Content Security Policy. At the end of the day the table will still display if the JavaScript fails.

Comment: i thought about js code but he insisted on css  solution ....  i just want to say your answer is complete and perfect    you are a  treasure for StackOverflow community

Comment: Thanks bud! Nice to be appreciated :-P

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post may be outdated, but I'd still like to share an alternative method I use for my data table. Instead of directly placing the content within the  tags, I wrap it with a  element and apply the following CSS properties: `max-width: 100%; width: max-content;`.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 350px;
}

div {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <div>This is a long text</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>short</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Normal</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>This is a long text</div>
    </td>
    <td class="long">
      <div>Sometimes very long text could appear that should break so the table does not get way too wide
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LongerWord</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 60px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 60px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> very long text djfkgjhghggdjgdkdfjext</td>
    <td>LonghgjerWord</td>
    <td>Normal</td>
    <td>This is a long text</td>
    <td>LonjhbvdfjghjdhgerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>Normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>short</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>LongerWord</td>
    <td>Normal</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked for. In this way, all of the td's will have a min-width of 60 px even if the text is `Normal` or `short`.

Comment: @SebastianI. you are right, I added an additional column to the example.

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan even though the last column appears smaller now somehow, this is not what i want, if you have only short words in a column it still breaks to soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
    td {
        word-break: break-word;
        white-space: pre-line;
        max-width: 150px; // change size as you need
        vertical-align: top;
        /*padding: 5px;*/
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    }
```

The above css will set your td to maximum width of 150 px (if the text is small then it will decrease the width to minimum required width for the text).

It breaks the line from where the last white space from the max-width reached.

If it does not contain a white space on that line then it will break from the max-width position.